# HTML How to show LineFeed from string file for show it in TextEdit

Tags: javascript, html, json, qt, qml

I want to show the json ini on QML TextEdit,i write .js to attain it.I compare two Json string and highlight different,but the hightlight display wrong,this is my code:

```
compare.js

function show_text(id,textStr1,textStr2)
{
    var t1 = textStr1
    var t2 = textStr2
    var t3 = ""
    var lmax = Math.max(t1.length,t2.length)
    var lmin = Math.min(t1.length,t2.length)

    for (var i = 0;i<lmax;i++)
    {
        if(t1.charAt(i) == t2.charAt(i))
        {
            var colorInfo_same =t1.charAt(i)
            t3 = t3 + colorInfo_same
        }
        else
        {
            var colorInfo_diff ="<p style='color:red'>"+t2.charAt(i)+"</p>"
            t3 = t3 + colorInfo_diff
        }
    }
    oldJson.text = t3
}
```

the textStr is json string like

```
{
    "bootup_resume_info": {
        "class": "",
        "maximum": "",
        "minimum": "",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "1"
    },
...
...
    "1st_operator_call": {
        "class": "",
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 0,
        "type": "int",
        "value": 0
    }
}
```

in qml:

```
TextEdit
{
   id:oldJson
   ...
   text:JsCompare.show_text(oldJson,initDataJson,initDataJson_com)
}
```

I do this want make difference jsonString's color for red. 
But the result let me confused. It show like this picture:

[image]

it seem get some wrong with display the LineFeed and Spacing.
Where is the problem with my code?What should i do?

Comment: you should either return something from the function or do non assign it to the `text` property. And I would set `textFormat : TextEdit.RichText`

Comment: That's what I set up before is `textFormat : TextEdit.RichText`,but the result like it. If i do non assign to `text` ,how show it ?

Comment: inside the function you assign some value to `text`. then the return value of the function (probably undefined) you again assign to the `text`. also, using `<p>` (paragraph) is not good idea, it just places every chat on the new line, use `<span>` instead